# Create a New Column by doing some operations on Existing Column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a column based on the existing column

Distinct Values in both columns will be 1 & 0

New Column Logic:

My New column will be 1 from index where 3 or More than 3 Consecutive 1's will start in Column1 and it will continue till where the index ends with 3 Consecutive 0

Example DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,
    1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1], columns = ['Col1'])
```

Expected Result

| Col1 | New_column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1, ], columns = ['Col1'])
output = []
state = df.iloc[0].values[0]

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    
    if i>len(df)-3:
            ip1=ip2=0
    else:
        ip1 = df['Col1'][i+1]
        ip2 = df['Col1'][i+2]

    if i-3<0:
        sp1=sp2=1
    else:
        sp1 = df['Col1'][i-1]
        sp2 = df['Col1'][i-2]
        sp3 = df['Col1'][i-3]
    
    if state == 1:
            
        if sp1 == 0 and  sp2== 0 and sp3 == 0:
            output.append(0)
            state = 0
            
        else:
            output.append(1)
    else:
        print(i, state, df['Col1'][i], ip1, ip2)
        if df['Col1'][i] == 1 and ip1 == 1 and ip2 == 1:
            output.append(1)
            state = 1
        else:
            output.append(0)
            
df['res'] = output
```

output:

[image]